# Stop Spring Security SavedDefaultRequest

Tags: java, spring, redirect, spring-security

We have an application using Spring Security(Version 4.0.3.RELEASE). When a user goes to an endpoint https://system.com/app/accountSummary?accountId=230 they get redirected to another page and the redirect page is set as we see this in the log:

```
DefaultSavedRequest added to Session: DefaultSavedRequest[http://system.com/app/accountSummary?accountId=230]
```

We then redirect them to a main page. When our user clicks to login it resets the DefaultSavedRequest. We see this in the logs: `DefaultSavedRequest added to Session: DefaultSavedRequest[http://system.com/app/mainpage]`

After the user logs in properly Spring Security is taking them back to the mainpage not the account screen they wanted.

**Is there a way to stop the DefaultSavedRequest from updating or check if it is set and not update it? 
Is it possible to do something at the page level? Or should I do this in a different fashion.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A teammate of mine created this solution:
AuthenticationPoint.java

```
SavedRequest savedRequest = null;
        if (request.getSession().getAttribute(ORIG_SAVED_REQUEST_URL) != null){
            saveURL = request.getSession().getAttribute(ORIG_SAVED_REQUEST_URL).toString();
            savedRequest = (SavedRequest) request.getSession().getAttribute(ORIG_SAVED_REQUEST);
            request.getSession().setAttribute(ORIG_SAVED_REQUEST_URL, saveURL);
            request.getSession().setAttribute(ORIG_SAVED_REQUEST, savedRequest);
            request.getSession().setAttribute(SPRING_SECURITY_SAVED_REQUEST, savedRequest);
            logger.debug("Session Variable ORIG-SAVED-REQUEST={}",savedRequest.getRedirectUrl());
        }
```

Then in Controller.java

```
if ((request != null) && (request.getSession() != null) &&
            (request.getSession().getAttribute(SPRING_SECURITY_SAVED_REQUEST) != null) ){
        savedRequest = (SavedRequest) request.getSession().getAttribute(SPRING_SECURITY_SAVED_REQUEST);
        request.getSession().setAttribute(ORIG_SAVED_REQUEST_URL, savedRequest.getRedirectUrl());
        request.getSession().setAttribute(ORIG_SAVED_REQUEST, savedRequest);
        logger.debug("Session Variable ORIG-SAVED-REQUEST={}",savedRequest.getRedirectUrl());
    }
```

Then he added this to the spring security xml:

```
<property name="alwaysUseDefaultTargetUrl"><value>false</value></property>
```

These changes resolved the issue in our application.